# What is an AWS IAM policy to allow a user to investigate, monitor, and deploy new versions to a specific Elasticbeanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

What permissions are needed to allow a user to deploy an Elastic Beanstalk application? I've used the Policy Generator to add all the permissions I believe are relevant to the ARN, but my developer is still being informed of the following error:

`User is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation`

I've also tried giving them full access to S3 using one of the managed policies, with no luck. Any ideas? Below is the attempted policy in use.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1492446920000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:CheckDNSAvailability",
                "elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplicationVersions",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplications",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationOptions",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationSettings",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentHealth",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentManagedActions",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentManagedActionHistory",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentResources",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEvents",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeInstancesHealth",
                "elasticbeanstalk:RebuildEnvironment",
                "elasticbeanstalk:RequestEnvironmentInfo",
                "elasticbeanstalk:RestartAppServer",
                "elasticbeanstalk:RetrieveEnvironmentInfo",
                "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "<redacted>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/